# how to select a substring that starts with x and ends with y through multilines and replace it

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to find a regex that selects a specific string that is defined by it's beginning & ending characters, through multilines, to be replaced by empty string. suppose that I have the following string for example:

I want to select every string that begins with `--` and ends with `;`

```
$str = 'some text --text_to_be_replaced; and another text -- text
to
be
replaced; and some text...;';
```

what I've tried:

```
$str = preg_replace('/--(.*);/s', '', $str);
```

but the returned result is: `some text` while the expected result is `some text and another text and some text...;`

Comment: It appears a detail is missing: what is expected result if you have `some text --text -- to be_replaced; here`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the expected result is `some text  here`

Comment: Then `'/--(.*?);/s'` will solve the problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, could you please re-post your expression here in the comments, it could be beneficial regardless of the edge-cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is too greedy, try this one:

```
/--([^;]*);/s
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/It2kpF/1/)